# How does `Skipcond` work in the MARIE assembly language?

Tags: loops, assembly, conditional-statements, pseudocode, marie

I am trying to understand the MARIE assembly language. I don't quite understand `skipcond` for
doing things like `<`, or `>`, or multiply or divide.

I am taking this simple program:

```
x = 1
while x < 10 do
x  = x +1
endwhile;
```

What I don't understand is how to use certain skip conditions:

```
Skipcond 800 if AC > 0,
Skipcond 400 if AC = 0,
Skipcond 000 if AC < 0
```

Now, I know I would subtract x from 10 and test using skipcond.

I am not sure which one and why. I guess if I knew how they really work maybe it would be easier to understand. Why is it used to compare to zero?

This is what I have:

```
100     load one
101     store x
102     subt ten
103     skipcond400  if x-10 = 0?   // or skpcond000 x -10 < 0??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while x < 10 do
    x  = x + 1
```

will jump out of the loop as soon as x equals 10. If you subtract 10 from x, you'll get a negative value until x equals 10 (and the value is 0). So using `skpcond000` would be wrong as it would jump out too soon. So `skpcond400` is correct.

Perhaps it is easier to understand if you change the C code so it will be closer to the assembly code:

```
Original:            while (x < 10) do
Subtract 10:         while ((x - 10) < 0) do
Use != instead of <: while ((x - 10) != 0) do
```

Also note that you have to increase `x` *after* the condition to reproduce identical behaviour to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. There are many ways to write this but I think this is the easiest way to understand what is happening in the loop. Note: usually variables are placed at the bottom of the program.

```
    while x<10
          x = x+1
```

```
Org 100  
       Load             One  / loads accumulator = 1 from a decimal constant
       Store             X   / initialize the var x = 1

loop,  Load           X      / loads x into the accumulator
       Subt             Ten  / compares x to 10 
       Skipcond         000  / if ac < 0 i.e. if x < 10 run rest of loop body
       JUMP             Endloop / if ac => 10  terminate loop
       Load              X    / begin the Loop
       ADD               One  / add 1 to x
       Store             X    / store new value in X
       JUMP              loop / continue loop

       Endloop           Halt / ends loop

One  = DEC 1   Constant
Ten  = DEC 10  Constant
X   = 0 Variable
```